# Is there a difference in reading spark dataset using filter vs basePath+full-filter-path?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

With respect to reading efficiency of a dataset partitioned by some column, is there a difference between:

```
// (1) read all dataset then filter
spark.read.parquet("/root/path").filter(col("mycolumn") === 42)
```

and

```
// (2) read directly the required data subset
spark.read.option("basePath", "/root/path").parquet("/root/path/mycolumn=42")
```

?

I ask this in a context where the data files are not stored in the same cluster as spark (so, no data locality). And I wonder in particular if in the case (1), it will retrieve the full dataset files on the spark cluster, then filter it (hopefully without actually reading the files), or if the filter will actually be done before retrieving the file which is what I expect the case (2) to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a huge difference.

In the first case you will read all file then filter, in the second case you will read only the selected file (the filter is alread done by the partitioning).

you can inspect if the filter is predicate pushdown by using `explain()` function.
In your `FileScan parquet` you will see `PushedFilters` and `PartitionFilters`

in your case, you should read the partitioned data without filter.

```
spark.read.option("basePath", "/root/path").parquet("/root/path/mycolumn=42")
```

Comment: That's what I expected then (and was afraid off cuz I need to require a change of storage from other people...). Spark doesn't infer a the `PartitionFilter` from a `.filter()` on a partition-column :(

Comment: I looked into it and I have a question: maybe I don't understand correctly what predicate pushdown filter are, but: if using a filter (i.e. method 2), adds a PartitionFilter to  the plans, isn't almost the same as using method (1) with basePath? I.e. when loading data, it will see that 'mycolumn' is a partition column, and thus filter directly on the file path?